# Scheduler + VBScript + ASP Classic authentication

Tags: authentication, vbscript, asp-classic, iis-7.5, job-scheduling

I'm automating a job which runs a VbScript that calls an ASP Classic page with WinHttpRequest. When I run this job from the Windows Scheduler (with highest privileges), the ASP page fails with a "Permission denied" error (it tries to copy a file to a different folder). When I run  the VbScript file manually, the operation succeeds.

The Web server is IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008, and anonymous access is enabled, impersonating as IUSR. My theory was that IIS shouldn't care who runs the script, the Scheduler or a human, and giving full access to IUSR should be fine. What is wrong with that?

In addition, when I check the AUTH_USER, LOGON_USER etc variables, they're always empty (both when I run the script manually and from the scheduler).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We actually set up a user with admin privilege to do this kind of thing.  Do you copy the file in the VBScript or in the ASP page?

Comment: `AUTH_USER` and `LOGON_USER` will be empty - you're using anonymous access.

Comment: That's the point -- I'm copying the files in the ASP page, so it shouldn't know how I run the VBScript file, right?

Comment: But the you have XSS issues, or rather you have security issues with accessing servers/locations outside of the domain of the IUSR account.

Comment: Hmm I thought XSS is strictly client side, no? Just to be clear, the whole thing is happening on the server: the scheduler, the vbscript file, the asp page, and the file it tries to access are all on one machine.

What's even more strange, it happens on two installations of the same system, but works perfectly on the others (the software is identical, but I'm not sure about the permissions).

Comment: Apologies - my brains been a bit porridgy lately - new baby and all. Check the permissions. I take it the file/folder structure is identical on all machines, and that the permissions are dientical? If that's the case, the only thing I could think of past that is that the IUSR acconuts all have equal privilege.